# Do I need to port code to python manually in Qt Creator Examples?

Tags: qt, pyside

First, I want to ask this question but there is no other site to ask.
I googled 30 minutes but can't find apropriate active forum to ask.
this is general question with no technical issue but I'll be thankful for comment

I'm absolute newby for Qt and PySide, wanted to execute Examples in Qt Creator in python language
There seems just C++ code in Qt Creator Examples menu

To port the code to python, Do I need to change code manually one by one with no other tool?

searched google for 30 minutes

Comment: There is no automated tool for this in Qt, you have to port them manually. There are some online tools that *try* to convert C++ to Python, but such tools are not 100% reliable: while C++ and Python have many common aspects (including some elements of the syntax), they are not interchangeable so easily, and such conversions almost always require human supervision, possibly with *good* knowledge of both languages.

Comment: Qt is a C++ framework. The Python bindings are a more recent addition. You can use your favorite editor/IDE for Python. I wouldn't really want to use Qt Creator for Python (although I guess it's possible). You should also be able to find examples and tutorials especially for Qt for Python.

Comment: @Friedrich I use VSCode for python, as you spoken Qt wouldn't fit for me to write python code

Comment: @Friedrich Qt Creator can be perfectly used for Python too. See the [related documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-python-development.html).

Comment: @musicamante thanks for clarifying. It wouldn't have been like Qt to forget about adapting Creator. I guess I just don't understand the question. There's Qt (for C++), there's Qt for Python. OP is trying to do C++ examples in Python, is that the problem?

Comment: @musicamante Qt for Python is just library, not independent program right? I wanted to port C++ examples to python code. What I want is study Qt using python but examples are all written in C++, it's problem. I'm not considering using C++. maybe it's better to not use C++ examples, instead write python program from scratch

Comment: There are plenty of [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/index.html)

Comment: @HoLeePuk You can simply go to the [PySide Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/index.html) to find everything you want, so there's no need to search elsewhere.

Comment: @HoLeePuk More technically, it's a *binding* that allows to use the Qt library (which is normally used in programs written in C++) from Python. The C++ examples can normally be easily converted to Python code (as long as you know both), and Qt also provides Python examples (linked above), but consider that I'm not 100% sure that they've been tested: most of the documentation contains examples automatically converted in Python that have not been checked yet (some of them are completely wrong), and that may also be true for the examples.

Comment: You can try `https://github.com/mugiseyebrows/seapeapea`, converted code will require tweaking and is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @HoLeePuk PS: it may be a little easier to download the [current PySide source code](https://github.com/qtproject/pyside-pyside-setup/tree/dev) which contains all the examples that have so far been ported to Python code. These include *.pyproject* files which can be opened and run in Qt Creator. The filepath of each PySide example is the same as the C++ ones shown in Qt Creator. (NB: the [PyQt source code](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6/#files) also contains ported examples, some of which aren't included in PySide).

Comment: very thankful for all the comments! 